# How to remove trailing separator from cout<< output console?

Tags: c++, console

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class... Ts>
void Fun(Ts... ts)
{
    cout <<"TS: "; ((cout<<ts<<", "), ..., (cout<<endl));
}

int main()
{
    Fun(1,'a',"blah", 2.13, 3.14f); //console: 1, a, blah, 2.13, 3.14, 
}
```

I want to remove the `,` separator after `3.14`, how can I do that?

I have tried `cout<<"\b \b"` and `cout<<'\b'`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do

```
template <class... Ts>
void Fun(Ts... ts)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    cout << "TS: "; (((cout << sep << ts), sep = ", "), ..., (cout << endl));
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0abb9fbda78367c0)

or even, as you have header:

```
template <class... Ts>
void Fun(Ts... ts)
{
    const char* sep = "TS: ";
    (((cout << sep << ts), sep = ", "), ..., (cout << endl));
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fda2e1c4b94e21c4)

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do:

```
template<class T = const char *, class... Ts>void Fun(T first = "", Ts... ts)
{
    cout << "TS: " << first; ((cout << ", " << ts), ..., (cout << endl));
}
```